Arm template error Unable to process template language expressions for resource
I'm having issue with arm template for deploying or updating Azure function app resource. I used this arm template below.
 {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
      "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
      "name": "[format('{0}/{1}', variables('functionAppName'), 'appsettings')]",
      "properties": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "[format('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={0};EndpointSuffix={1};AccountKey={2}', variables('storageAccountName'), environment().suffixes.storage, listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')), '2021-09-01').keys[0].value)]",
        "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('applicationInsightsName')), '2020-02-02').InstrumentationKey]",
        "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION": "~4",
        "ftpsState": "Disabled",
        "minTlsVersion": "1.2"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('applicationInsightsName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('functionAppName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName'))]"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

I'm using Azure DevOps pipeline to deploy this template however I'm having this error
Status Message: Unable to process template language expressions for resource '/subscriptions/subscriptionID/resourceGroups/DE3/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/functionap-DE3/config/appsettings' at line '176' and column '9'. 'Unable to evaluate language function 'format': the format is invalid: 'Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list. With correlationId without clear root cause.
I have tested the template directly on Azure portal and it was able to passed validation checks but when deploy through azure pipeline it failed. Can you please let me know the fix on this.
Tried to change formatting for this code line "name": "[format('{0}/{1}', variables('functionAppName'), 'appsettings')]", into "name": "[concat('{0}/{1}', variables('functionAppName'), 'appsettings')]",
when deployed the error is still the same.

Have you tried using concat function in name field. @F6 Striker

Tried this syntax "name": "[concat(variables('functionAppName'), '/appsettings')]", still encounter the same error posted above Unable to process template language expressions for resource
We used deploy yml for arm template deployment in Azure pipeline.
using AzurePowerShell@5 task ` $templatePath = "${{ parameters.templatelocation }}/${{ parameters.app }}.json"
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName ${{ parameters.env }} -TemplateFile $templatePath -TemplateParameterObject $parameter_values``


Arm template error Unable to process template language expressions for resource

Looking at the error it seems to be AzureWebJobsStorage which shows when we have multiple inputs while using format will end up being null or invalid while using devops pipeline.
Instead of using format try using concat by break the AzureWebJobsStorage property into multiple steps which helps in troubleshoot the issue.
configuration:
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "functionAppName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "storageAccountName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "applicationInsightsName": {
      "type": "string",
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]"
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2021-09-01",
      "name": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard_LRS"
      },
      "kind": "StorageV2",
      "properties": {}
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components",
      "apiVersion": "2020-02-02",
      "name": "[parameters('applicationInsightsName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "Application_Type": "web"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
      "name": "[parameters('functionAppName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "kind": "functionapp",
      "properties": {
        "siteConfig": {
          "appSettings": [
            {
              "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
              "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', parameters('storageAccountName'), ';EndpointSuffix=', environment().suffixes.storage, ';AccountKey=', listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName')), '2021-09-01').keys[0].value)]"
            },
            {
              "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
              "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', parameters('applicationInsightsName')), '2020-02-02').InstrumentationKey]"
            },
            {
              "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
              "value": "~4"
            },
            {
              "name": "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE",
              "value": "1"
            },
            {
              "name": "ftpsState",
              "value": "Disabled"
            },
            {
              "name": "minTlsVersion",
              "value": "1.2"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', parameters('applicationInsightsName'))]"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Deployment:


refer:
Concat variable with string in Azure ARM Template answered by Repcak
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-string
